# Want to put IP address v4 of my specifically named adapter into a variable using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ip, adapter, named

I have several network adapters on my PC.

I want to simply get the IP Address v4 (with no headers or extras) of the adapter called a specific name and store it into a variable for further use.

I am able to return the IP Address with headers but not what I want.

Please Help - thanks.

Here is what I tried:

```
$ipa = Get-NetIPAddress |
    Where-Object { $_.IfIndex -eq 19 -and $_.InterfaceAlias -eq "LAN2" -and $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4" } |
    Select-Object { $_.IPAddress }
```

**Edit:**

```
$ipa = Get-NetIPAddress |  where {$_.InterfaceAlias -eq "LAN2" -and    
$_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"} | select -expandproperty ipaddress
```

The above code is returning both my wired adaptors' addresses but it is returning just the Ip address at least and nothing else (thanks Anthony)

There is ONLY one called "LAN2" - i only need that one - so still stuck

Update : 
Austin Frenchs second solution works great - will test Owls today later - thanks everyone so far - great helpful community

Comment: Hi, please use the edit button to add your code to your question so we can help you : ).

Comment: What @sodawillow said. Please provide a [mcve], and also indicate your PowerShell **and** OS version because PowerShell's networking cmdlets changed a lot in the more recent versions.

Comment: try changing that last part to `select -expandproperty ipaddress`

Comment: sorry ive made a mess of that - i cant understand the add code instructions they are extremely confusing - i indented by 4 spaces as instructed - sorry

Comment: thanks Anthony your change gives only the  IP Address - BUT still getting 2 adaptor IP addresses  returned

Comment: Please edit again and include the incorrect return you get : ) _also, your formatting issues were only caused by a lack of linebreaks_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple one liner

```
(Get-NetIPConfiguration).ipv4address | where {$_.InterfaceAlias -eq "Lan2"} | foreach { write-host $_.ipaddress}
```

get from enabled network

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE  | select Ipaddress
```

only from particular adapter and ipv4

```
Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
  Where-Object { $_.IPEnabled -eq $true } | 
  Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddress } | 
  Foreach-Object { [IPAddress]$_ } | 
  Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'LAN2'  } | 
  Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddressToString }
```

Comment: thanks Owl - your first one works great returns just what i want 2nd one returns all enabled adapters (and IPv6 addresses not needed) your 3rd one returns nothing (you have mixed up the adapter name with (Address Family) - but thanks for the first

Comment: i've chosen Owls first solution  for being the most efficient and using not much code :)

Answer (score 1):

Without access to get-netipaddress, here is a very dirty and long one liner. Change out "Local Area Connection" for your network's name.

```
((([System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | ? {$_.Name -eq  "Local Area Connection"}).GetIPProperties() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'UniCastAddresses' | ? {$_.IPv4Mask -ne
"0.0.0.0"}) | Select Address).Address.IPAddressToString
```

With Get-netIpAddress, I suspect this would also work:

```
$ipa = (Get-NetIPAddress |
    Where-Object { $_.IfIndex -eq 19 -and $_.InterfaceAlias -eq "LAN2" -and $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4" } | `
    Select-Object { $_.IPAddress }).IPAddress
```

Comment: Hi Austin your first answer crashes with this error ....................................
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At \\\POWERSHELL-SCRIPTS\put_ip_into_variable.ps1:34 char:1
+ $ipa = ((([System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNet ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: BUT YOUR SECOND SOLUTION WORKS A TREAT !! THANKS

Comment: Great news, and don't forget to an accept an answer (the check mark) when you have found something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you are looking for by first getting a list of all network adapters on the machine using `get-wmiobject`, selecting the name you want, then piping it to `get-netipaddress` and then selecting the `IPAddress` property  as shown below.

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "YOUR_NAME"} | Get-NetIPAddress).IPAddress
```

Comment: Hi Mike Thanks - but your solution returns a blank

Comment: I just tested again on one of my systems and got the correct result.  When you just run `get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter` do you see the adapter you are looking for?

Comment: Ahh I think you might be trying the Adaptor (hover over) "description" field - when I put that i it works - not with Adaptor name - you more or less got just dont need 1pv6 -cheers :) slightly confusing the microsoft called it "name" in powershell - it appears they MEAN "description" as that works for me